# How to execute a certain part using makefile in C (LINUX)

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I am developing a `C program` that calls 2 functions, `func1()` and `func2()`.

Here is the code

```
void func1(void){/*...*/}
void func2(void){/*...*/}

int main(){
    func1();
    func2();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way that when I `compile` the program using `make` and a `certain flag`, it just executes `func1()` and if I compile using another flag then it only executes `func2()`?

How to make such a `makefile`? Can anyone provide me with a makefile that does this job?

Comment: You should read about preprocessor directives like `#ifdef` etc. And then you need to provide the related macro to your compiler. For many compilers that is done via `-D...` option. Just add this to your exising flags for C compiler in your makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-D` flag of the compiler:

```
cc -o demo demo.c -Dfunc=func1
```

then

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1(void) { puts("1"); }
void func2(void) { puts("2"); }

int main(void)
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

You can also pass the function as an argument to `make`:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -Wpedantic -Wall

action: demo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) demo.c -o demo -Dfunc=$(argument)

clean:
    rm -f demo
```

call `make` using:

```
make action argument=func1
```

or

```
make action argument=func2
```

But if you really want to do that:

```
int main(){
    func1();
    func2();
```

call both functions inside `main`, you should use another approach (although this solution seems quite sticky to me):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func0(void) { /* do nothing */ }
void func1(void) { puts("1"); }
void func2(void) { puts("2"); }

#ifdef delete_func1
#define func1 func0
#endif

#ifdef delete_func2
#define func2 func0
#endif

int main(void)
{
    func1();
    func2();
    return 0;
}
```

compile using:

```
cc -o demo demo.c -Ddelete_func1
```

or

```
cc -o demo demo.c -Ddelete_func2
```

then the `Makefile` should look like:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -Wpedantic -Wall

func1: demo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) demo.c -o demo -Ddelete_func2

func2: demo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) demo.c -o demo -Ddelete_func1

clean:
    rm -f demo
```

call it using:

```
make func1
```

or

```
make func2
```

you can delete both functions using `-D` twice:

```
cc -o demo demo.c -Ddelete_func1 -Ddelete_func2
```